# how can I omit modules with initramfs-tools?

Tags: debian, initramfs

In debian-like distros, initramfs-tools is used to automatically generate ramdisk. I only find options to add extra modules via initramfs.conf or /etc/initramfs-tools/modules. But how can I blacklist some modules? I definitely do not want to use list in initramfs.conf which is an allowlist.

In fedora, there is configuration file that I can put something like `omit_drivers+=driver-a driver-b` in dracut configuration to avoid some modules. Then I do not need to rebuild the ramdisk after kernel/driver update. How can I do the same in debian/ubuntu?

Comment: so there is no way to do this in ubuntu or debian?

Comment: how can I close my own question? Since no one answered here. I posted also on askubuntu and get a good answer. https://askubuntu.com/a/1433196/862165